# Spring Cloud Gateway with Kafka Broadcaster

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on a project and working on spring-cloud-gateway and kafka broadcaster.  The project  uses spring-cloud-gateway, so that means that there is no any controller. The requests are being forwarded to another microservice by using spring-cloud-gateway.

My problem is that I need to send a message to a kafka topic. I know that there are some examples about amazon sqs and sns with spring-cloud-gateway. Is there any example for using of kafka and spring-cloud-gateway?

Comment: Clients must connect directly to the Kafka brokers. Any gateway/proxy/load balancer doesn't really work in context of Kafka protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://dzone.com/articles/developing-async-microservices-architecture-using) tutorial

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class MicroserviceWebApplication extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "true");
        SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceWebApplication.class, args);
    }
   @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```